# How to dynamically update an open Bootstrap 5 modal backdrop and keyboard properties

Tags: jquery, bootstrap5-modal

I have Bootstrap 5 modal that is displayed. I wish to dynamically change it's backdrop and keyboard so that for a specific action i.e. button press, the modal will stay static. This code does not work:

```
bModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(parent.jQuery('.modal'));
bModal._config.keyboard = false;
bModal._config.backdrop = "static";
```

I checked console.log I can confirm that I am targetting the correct modal but for some reason the config does not stay static.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

using .modal() might work better for you!

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:'static', keyboard:false});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. For some reason trying to access the modal via $('#id') and or jQuery('#id') produces a null value. Even using the document.getElementByid('#id'). Even though the modal is right in front of my eyes and I am interacting with it, for some reason when i feed it to bootstrap.Modal it acts as if the object does not exist and so it creates a new instance of it which I think is the issue here. Are there any tips to access an existing modal via jQuery?

Comment: You can access it via following                 $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

Comment: does not work for me either

Answer (score 0):

Use vanilla javascript instead

```js
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal('#myModal')
// Show the modal
// modal.show();

// Hide the modal
modal.hide();
```

Comment: It's about backdrop and keyboard-options, not show or hide the modal.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should refer to first index

```
const $modal = jQuery('.modal')[0];
let modalInstance = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance($modal);

modalInstance._config.backdrop = false;
modalInstance._config.keyboard = false;
```

in vanilla it's equivalent to

```
document.getElementByClass('modal');
```